# Save multiples checkboxList

Tags: yii2

I have a form with a CheckboxList generated through a model "Candidates" and I need to make a vote where the voter can select multiple candidates and record.

How do I 'pick up' the selected candidates and write to the votes table / model ??

Form "votos"

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'candidato_id')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map(Candidatos::find()->where(['status' => 1])->orderBy("nome ASC")->all(), 'id', 'nome')); ?>

<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'eleicao_id', ['value' => 1]) ?>

<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'cargo_id', ['value' => 1]) ?>

<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'urna_id', ['value' => 1]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Model "Votos"

```
namespace app\models;
use Yii;

class Votos extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'votos';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['eleicao_id', 'candidato_id', 'cargo_id', 'urna_id', 'data'], 'required'],
            [['eleicao_id', 'candidato_id', 'cargo_id', 'urna_id'], 'integer'],
            [['data'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'eleicao_id' => 'Eleicao ID',
            'candidato_id' => 'Candidato ID',
            'cargo_id' => 'Cargo ID',
            'urna_id' => 'Urna ID',
            'data' => 'Data',
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller "VotosControllers"

```
public function actionVotacao()
    {
        $model = new Votos();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('votacao', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: You have to overwrite save method in your model.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Okay, can you show me an example or a post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly unrelated, but if you haven't already I would strongly suggest making sure you have something like xdebug set up so you can quickly see what your code is doing as you make your changes. Being able to set breakpoints and see what your form has submitted can go a long way to helping you solve a problem like this on your own and the framework becomes less mysterious. With that out of the way, something like the following MIGHT help as far as the controller goes. There is other validation you would want to do as well I should add. Maybe the `each` validator which you can [read up on here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#each). For `actionUpdate()` you would need to look at deleting all the values that relate to the related id and re-populate with the new ones, checkout `deleteAll`. Hopefully I don't get smashed too hard for providing this solution which is not a drop in solution.

```
public function actionVotacao()
{
    $model = new Votos();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

        if ($model->save()) {
            // Save the checkbox values.
            if (!empty(Yii::$app->request->post()['Votos']['XXXX'])) { // Your form should give you an idea of what the XXXX should be, xdebug is also your friend.
                foreach (Yii::$app->request->post()['Votos']['XXXX'] as $candidato_id) {
                    $candidato = new Candidato();
                    $candidato->id = $candidato_id;

                    if (!$candidato->save()) print_r($candidato->errors);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your logic helped me understand. I will try to know more about xdebug or another.